# Одинаковая фоновая музыка в разных активити

Tags: android, аудио

Как запустить музыкальный поток и сделать так, чтобы он не прерывался если пользователь переходит на другие активити?

Фоновый звук бы непрерывный.

Comment: В сервисе запустить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что бы не прерывался - пожалуй стоит запустить его не в активити, а в сервисе. Код примерно такой:

```
    private void startPlayback() { 
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
mPlayer.prepare();
mPlayer.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(LOG_TAG, "MediaPlayer prepare() failed");
}
}

// стоп

private void stopPlayback() {
mPlayer.release();
mPlayer = null;

}
```

Более подробно тут -  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html